# No matter which port I use in my Spring Boot project, it shows up every time that Web server failed to start. Port #### was already in use

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

**When I hit my API endpoints it redirects to the spring default login page although I didn't use any spring security ** How can I solve this problem. And also no matter which port I used always failed to run showing the avobe error.

```html
2021-03-18 22:20:28.987  INFO 1136 --- [  restartedMain] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 10ca6485-f9b1-45fd-8422-7f521974e807

2021-03-18 22:20:29.058  INFO 1136 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5afcaa40, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1ecd6c38, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@57c0b97a, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@70e744e9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@ddc05c8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@72ab48fb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@77c3d4dd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@53c95e38, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@456f30b5, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@723b9c48, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@217298a9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6f9f366c, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3487264d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@bba9566, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2c1e9611]
2021-03-18 22:20:30.156  INFO 1136 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils
```

```html
2021-03-18 22:20:30.366  INFO 1136 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2021-03-18 22:20:31.473  INFO 1136 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:145)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:135)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
```

```html
at com.productservice.ProductServiceApplication.main(ProductServiceApplication.java:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:574)
```

```html
2021-03-18 22:20:31.473  WARN 1136 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2021-03-18 22:20:31.474  INFO 1136 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_PRODUCT-SERVICE/localhost:product-service:8888 - was unable to refresh its cache! This periodic background refresh will be retried in 30 seconds. status = Cannot execute request on any known server stacktrace = com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1101)
```

```html
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

2021-03-18 22:20:32.556  INFO 1136 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
2021-03-18 22:20:33.561  INFO 1136 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on DELETE request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/PRODUCT-SERVICE/localhost:product-service:8888": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on DELETE request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/PRODUCT-SERVICE/localhost:product-service:8888": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.cancel(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:87)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
    at com.netflix.discovery.sh
```

```html
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-18 22:20:33.651 ERROR 1136 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8888 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8888 or configure this application to listen on another port.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

**When I hit my API endpoints it redirects to the spring default login page although I didn't use any spring security ** How can I solve this problem. And also no matter which port I used always failed to run showing the avobe error.

Comment: Is this your eureka discovery service project? Check pom for any spring security dependency if you have added

Comment: yes, eureka client service. I used spring security in another service

Comment: @mahesh sir how can resolve this problem?

Comment: check your discovery service configuration. Seems the problem could be there. Can you add code